# Check if object is null and return null

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I'm doing a query to an object. My question is if nothing returns is it technically null. I want to return null if it is.

```
People person = [SELECT Id, Type FROM People WHERE (Type LIKE '%Construction%') limit 1];

if (person == null){
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The syntax in your code throws a QueryException if you try it, and there are no records to return. Instead, use one of the other common patterns. This is one that I use:

```
People person; // is null
for(People record: [SELECT Type FROM People WHERE Type LIKE '%Construction%' LIMIT 1]) {
  person = record;
}
return person; // will return null or a single record
```

Comment: *The syntax in your code throws a QueryException if you try it* -- only if there's no record returned.

Comment: @JayantDas That's what I meant, of course, but I went ahead and clarified.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to check for the number of records returned:

```
People[] persons = [...];
if (persons.size() == 0) return null;
```

as your code as written will generate this exception if no records match:

> System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Comment: Or simply isEmpty() :)

Comment: @Eric I always forget that method...

Answer (score 1):

Change the code to:

```
People[] people = [SELECT Id, Type FROM People WHERE (Type LIKE '%Construction%') LIMIT 1];

if (people.size() == 0){
    return null;
} else {
    return people[0];
}
```