# Null check condition for User object SOQL query

Tags: apex, soql, if, null

Below is the query I have used :-

```java
User singleUser= [SELECT id,name,alias FROM user 
    WHERE alias = 'random' AND name = 'Random Name' LIMIT 1];
```

In the IF condition I want to check for the null condition for this SOQL query...like if this query has returned an empty result or not. How can i do that?

I have tried to put

```java
system.debug('size ============= ' + singleUser.isblank());
system.debug('size ============= ' + singleUser.isempty());
```

But it throws me the error :-

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void isblank() from the
> type User

Comment: User record (SObject) doesn't have any methods like isblank or isempty (which is apparent from the error message). You need to use "List<User> users" instead and then you can check using "users.isEmpty()".

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning the query result to sObject directly, which would work fine if the SOQL returns a result(single).

But, if there is no result you will get the below error:

> List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Also, the `User` object(sObject) doesn't have methods `isBlank` and `isEmpty`, which are methods for `list` type.

So it would be safer to assign the SOQL result to a List variable, like:

```
List<User> userList = [SELECT id,name,alias FROM user WHERE alias = 'random' AND name = 'Random Name' LIMIT 1];
```

Post that, you can add a check on the `list` as given below

```
if(userList.isEmpty()) {
}
```

Refer [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?type=1&mode=1&id=000328824) article for more details

Answer (score 1):

You should use list to query the records instead of assigning the values to a sObject variable. It will throw QueryException if no records found.

```
List<User> singleUser= [SELECT id,name,alias FROM user WHERE alias = 'random' AND name = 'Random Name' LIMIT 1];
if(!singleUser.isEmpty()){
    //do the logic
    system.debug(singleUser[0].name); //Access the record value    
}
```

Also, There is no such method on isblank() or isEmpty() to check for sObject variable.

---

Or You can use this:- [Check if object is null and return null](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/254673/check-if-object-is-null-and-return-null)

```
User singleUser; // is null
for(User record: [SELECT id,name,alias FROM user WHERE alias = 'random' AND name = 'Random Name' LIMIT 1]) {
  singleUser = record;
}
```

here, you can check:-

```
if(singleUser != null){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you really need a user at this point in the code, you can also use a try & catch
and in the catch you can show the user a message or just return as you can't continue without a user.

Checks for null or isBlank is only a good solution if you still have something todo when there is no user.

Otherwise I would do a try & catch with err-handling in the catch.